# Umbraco razor displaying iframe

Tags: iframe, razor, umbraco

I have set this up so that in umbraco I paste the iframe link into a multiple textfield, and then in the XSLT I would do something like:

```
  <xsl:value-of select="embedCode" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Which would display the video fine, but I am now trying to do this in razor and I can't seem to get it to display at all? I've tried using html raw but can't get it working

This is basically what I have at the moment which just spits out the iframe url

```
 <div>@item.embedCode</div>
```

Anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input please?

Comment: What code is outputted now when you look in the source of the HTML and what is outputted when you use @Html.Raw(item.embedCode)?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Html.Raw(item.embedCode) works!